# Filter a List of Dictionary logic problem

Tags: c#

In my `List<Dictionary<string,string>> listOfAnimal` I need to filter out the records that are equal to Name `Ant`.

The dictionary consist of the following elements.

```
[
{
 "id":"5",
 "name": "Ant",
 "age":"6"
},
{
 "id":"52",
 "name": "Elephant",
 "age":"1"
},
{
 "id":"15",
 "name": "Ant",
 "age":"6"
},
{
 "id":"9",
 "name": "Ape",
 "age":"16"
}


]
```

So basically, I need to filter out a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` where the `name` of the Animal is `Ant`. My approach is as follows:

```
var filtered= listOfAnimal.Values.Where(x=> x.Equals("Ant")).ToList();
```

The above doesn't give other elements in the dictionary, instead only matches the name.

Can someone help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you defined a list of dictionaries for that job. You don't need a dictionary for that job, and if you use one, the keys need to be unique anyway (id would be better than name for a key).
If you write a class for you animal like

```
public class Animal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint age { get; set; }
}
```

and put the instances of it in a List/Enumerable you can do

```
var filtered = raw.Where(animal=>animal.Name == "Ant");
```

to get only the ants.

Answer (score 1):

Not really 100% clear what's your case but give this a go.

`var ants = listOfAnimal.SelectMany(d => d).Where(d => d.Value.Equals("Ant", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));`

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
var filtered = listOfAnimal
    .Where(x => x.TryGetValue("name", out var name) && name == "Ant")
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of dictionaries, and you want to filter out (exclude) dictionaries that have a key `"name"` with value `"Ant"`.  You can do this as follows:

```
var filteredList = listOfAnimal
    .Where(d =>
           {
               string name;
               if (!d.TryGetValue("name", out name))
                   // Include the dictionary if it completely lacks a "name" entry.
                   return true;
               // Include the dictionary if the "name" entry is something other than "Ant".
               return name != "Ant";
           })
    .ToList();
```

If you really wanted filter out dictionaries that **do not** have a key `"name"` with value `"Ant"` (your question is slightly ambiguous), you would do it as follows:

```
var filteredList = listOfAnimal
    .Where(d =>
           {
               string name;
               if (!d.TryGetValue("name", out name))
                   // Exclude the dictionary if it completely lacks a "name" entry.
                   return false;
               // Include the dictionary if the "name" entry equals "Ant".
               return name == "Ant";
           })
    .ToList();
```

In your current code you seem to be trying to filter out key/value pairs from a single dictionary rather than entire dictionaries from a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>`.

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ojMC0A).